# SQL Removing a filter from an unpivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table, unpivot

I have this unpivot table and I wish to remove the filter that is applied to it.

```
DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsUnpivot as NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)



select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(year(EcoDate)) 
                    from PhdRpt.RptCaseEco
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('PhdRpt.RptCaseEco') 
         and C.name Like 'Net%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')


set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select reportruncaseid, year(Ecodate) as EcoYear, val, col
        from phdrpt.rptcaseeco

        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ('+ @colsUnpivot +')
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for ecoyear in ('+ @colspivot +')

      ) p ORDER BY reportruncaseid'


exec(@query)
```

This table worked before because all the columns had a prefix of "Net" but now there are other columns that are being filtered out because they do not begin with "Net". I tried to remove ---  and C.name Like 'Net%' ---    but I keep getting these errors:

`Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The type of column "EcoDate" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.`

`Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'reportruncaseid'.`

`Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'Ecodate'.`

Here is what the table looks like
[image: Table]

Comment: What is the table structure of the table you are unpivoting?  When you apply an unpivot the datatypes must be the same, so you might need to apply a cast prior to unpivot but you need to provide more details.

Comment: I am pivoting the EcoDate and unpivoting the rest of the columns dynamically. We will not know the number of columns or the number of ecodates in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter to get the list of columns to UNPIVOT can be removed but if there are columns that you do not want to UNPIVOT then you will need to exclude them:

```
select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('PhdRpt.RptCaseEco') 
         and C.name not in ('reportruncaseid', 'Ecodate')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

This will return all of the columns to unpivot, except  `reportruncaseid` and `Ecodate` (or other columns you do not want unpivoted). So the full query will be:

```
DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsUnpivot as NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(year(EcoDate)) 
                    from PhdRpt.RptCaseEco
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('PhdRpt.RptCaseEco') 
         and C.name not in ('reportruncaseid', 'Ecodate')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select reportruncaseid, year(Ecodate) as EcoYear, val, col
        from phdrpt.rptcaseeco

        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ('+ @colsUnpivot +')
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for ecoyear in ('+ @colspivot +')

      ) p ORDER BY reportruncaseid'

exec(@query);
```

Also if you have columns that are different datatypes, then you will have to cast them to the same datatype prior to applying the unpivot.

Comment: How would you cast an unknown number of columns?

Comment: @RolandP How many columns are you talking about here?  100? You might have to look at other methods to create the sql string with the cast, including cursors.

Comment: It could be 100. It is really up to the end user. These tables can be changed at their discretion which is why I needed this to be dynamic.

Comment: @RolandP So the users have the ability to change the datatypes on the table?  What is the current datatype on the table?  Can you edit your OP with the create table for `rptcaseeco`?

Comment: They can add new columns from our program.

Comment: Woooooah. Your users can add columns to your database?

Comment: They add columns in the program and it adds those columns into the rptcaseeco table.

Comment: @RolandP Are they able to select any datatype for the columns or what are the datatypes that can be added?

Comment: @ bluefeet I just talked to the developers and they are going to make it to where the only datatype they can add is a float.   I resolved the issue by using this instead: and C.name NOT IN('ReportRunCaseId', 'ReportId', 'EcoDate'). These were the three columns that were not float datatypes. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RolandP That will make your life considerably easier.

Comment: @Zane Different users might have different or additional data that they need to display. They add that data and it makes a column. The column has data for every year. In my sql code I needed to take the columns and make them rows. Then take the years and make them column names.